# Keep repeating labels in db?

Tags: database

If I have repeating labels throughout the site - is it a good way to keep them in a database so that I can change all of them in one place? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1):

If you do use a DB make sure they are not repeating in the DB :)

Answer (score 0):

What environment are you in?  Resource files might be a better way than a database.  In ASP.Net, you can use them for multiple languages also (I'm not familiar with resource files in other environments).